# Making a function that adds a number to a variable every second in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hey so basically I want to create a function that at every 1 second adds 1 or a changeable number to another variable.

I have been searching the internet for this but haven't been able to find it. I am guessing that it should be fairly simple.

Comment: Anything you tried yourself?

Comment: `setInterval()` to make something happen every second.  `++` operator to add one to a variable's value.  If it were me though, I'd just keep track of what time you started.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var counter =0;
var value = 1; //the number to add.  You can change it by modifying the variable
setInterval(function() {
  counter+= value;
},1000);
```

but, if you want to add 1 per second, a much more efficient way would be

```
//set the initial value
var start = Date.now();

//create a function you can call anytime to get the diff
function getCurrentDiff() {
   return (Date.now() - start)/1000;

}
```

then you don't have to be constantly running the add function, which gets expensive over time.

Comment: Ok thanks! I hope this will work out for what I am wanting it to do.

Answer (score 0):

setInterval or setTimeout?

```
setTimeout(function(){number++;},1000);
```

or

```
setInterval(function(){number++;},1000);
```

Comment: setTimeout will only do it once, unless you reset the timeout within the inner function.